# Is there a camera exposure meter in Blender similar to a DSLR, so I can color correct outside of blender? All I see is a histogram

Tags: rendering, node-editor, camera, image, filmic-blender

### Problem / Background

Hi! I want to match some footage from a DSLR camera with a green screen and put it in a blender scene. For people who don't know, on a DSLR you set the aperture, ISO, and shutter speed until the meter hits the center at 0, like this:

`-3 ....-2 ....-1 .... 0 .... +1 .... +2 .... +3`

And later on when editing, as long as you're at the center, you have far more creative room to change the scene as you like. And I was wondering if blender had an exposure meter just like that, so matching footage is easier, and color correction could be done in another program *(like DaVinci Resolve / Fusion)*.

I checked the blender docs, and the closest thing I can find is a [histogram.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/editors/image/sidebar.html?highlight=histogram#) Which is still very useful if nothing is blowing out black or white, but not what I was hoping for. I also saw the [exposure](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/render_settings/film.html?highlight=exposure) setting, but it's not a meter either. And all the youtube videos I saw have people using nodes to color correct green screen footage to the blender scene all in blender. Which works, but I'd rather do color correction in DaVinci because it's far better *(Chroma Key / DeltaKeyer node is super fast and easy, etc).*

If no exposure meter exists, would you say the best way for the time being is to just use nodes and eyeball it? Either that, or take take a rendered image of each scene, and match my footage to it in DaVinci?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily switch to "False color" view transform, in rendered view, to check your exposure and lighting: red is overexposed, blue is underexposed, green is midlevel.

[image]

Then, once rendered, in the image editor window you can right click on any pixel to read its exact values in the bottom zone of the window.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you very much!